# Flash Player trust file not working with Embedded browser on linux

Tags: javascript, browser, flash, xulrunner

I have an application which embeds a browser based on `Xulrunner` inside it. I have couple of flash swf files I need to load in the browser. The swf files talk with a JavaScript to change the page title and also to change the URL when I am browsing through the content in the URL. I need the URL change because I need to remember where I was in the flash content so that I can go directly to that place in the flash file when I open my browser the next time.

To let the swf file do this I created a cfg file and placed it into the Flash Player Trust folder( I tried both the local one at `/home/user/.macromedia/Flash_Player/#Security/FlasPlayerTrust` and global trust file location at `/etc/adobe/FlashPlayerTrust` ) , but I didn't get the expected result. I debugged into my app and found that the swf never reset the Title of the page( which indicates that the JavaScript was blocked) . It works fine from a firefox browser but not from inside my embedded browser. My app also works fine on windows and Mac . This is observed only on Linux. Can any body think of what else I need to do get my javascript embedded in  the flash file working?

Comment: I haven't used XULRunner, but it sounds like the browser you're using may not support ExternalInterface.  Have you checked into the specs?  Does the browser support the NPAPI?

Comment: Xulrunner is the engine that firefox also uses. Xulrunner is built with NPAPI support. So my browser should also support it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use flash app dependencies inside embedded browsers inside desktop applications.